# Skeletons: non-interactive subskeletons?

Tags: skeleton

[§12 Skeleton Language](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Skeleton-Language.html) lists, as an element of a skeleton input list,

> ***skeleton***
>
> ```
>   Subskeletons are inserted recursively, not once, but as often as
>   the user enters something at the subskeletons interactor. Thus there
>   must be a `str` in the subskeleton. They can also be used
>   non-interactively, when prompt is a lisp-expression that returns
>   successive list-elements.
> ```

As seems to be common in the skeleton documentation, the terminology is obscure and self-contradictory.  I've tried various ways to realise the structure described, but none of my attempts have worked.  Here is one of them:

```
(define-skeleton _skel
  "Test skeleton"
  nil
  ('("Seventeen" "Nineteen") "Should be two values, 17 and 19:" str \n))
```

Invoking `_skell` results in "`Should be two values, 17 and 19:`" appearing in the buffer, and an error of `setq: Wrong type argument: stringp, ("Seventeen" "Nineteen")` appearing in the message buffer.

What am I missing to make this use of subskeletons non-interactively, with either static values or a dynamic lisp-expression returning the values?

Thanks!

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Reading the documentation what I do understand is that the interactor (set to `nil` in your example) should be what returns the list elements and not trying to pass a list to str which expects an atom.

Comment: I've tried that, too.  Of course, AFAIUI, subskeletons need an interactor, too.  Hence the confusion.  Every combo I've tried has resulted in the same error. :-(

Comment: Even an example here would be a big help.  The code in `skeleton.el` contains a lot of Deep Magic.

Answer (score 1):

It's a long time since the question was asked but I figured I would answer since it took me hours to figure this out. This [section](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SkeletonMode#h5o-8) from emacswiki tipped me off.

The first item of a subskeleton has to be either a string (used as a prompt) *or* an s-expression that returns a string when evaluated. This string can be produced interactively (using `skeleton-read`) or non interactively. That means your example needs a function that returns a different string for each call. Iterating over a list like this can be done with a helper function that tracks the state of the iteration with a closure.

```lisp
(defun make-list-iterator (list)
  (let ((ls (cons 'discard list))) ; provide item to discard on first call
    (lambda ()
      (setf ls (cdr ls))
      (car ls))))
```

You can then make your example work as you expect like so:

```lisp
(define-skeleton _skel
  "Test skeleton"
  nil
  ;; Save function doing the iteration in a skeleton-local variable
  '(fset 'v1 (make-list-iterator '("Seventeen" "Nineteen")))
  ((v1) "Should be two values, 17 and 19:" str \n))
```